# "Begin transaction" usage in multiple delete/insert

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I created an adhoc which has lots of delete/insert action.
For data integrity, I would like to rollback all if any action goes wrong.
The following is the pseudo code:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
      INSERT INTO New_Table VALUES(......)
      DELETE FROM Old_Table
      COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Is there any performance issue here? I will use this logic about 10 times for insert/delete data in this adhoc.

Comment: If you need to keep your data safe then transaction are the thing to use. Your code above looks fine. Based on just the above i don't think you are going to do any better.    Note that in simple terms the transaction will assume things will work so the commit is almost as quick as no transaction at all.  Its only when doing rollbacks you really need to worry about performance.

Comment: If you want extra safety, you may also want to turn `SET XACT_ABORT ON`. See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx